# Change Windows 7 Lock Screen Logo changed by Dell Data Protection Access

Tags: windows-7, dell-latitude, fingerprint, ctrl-alt-delete

When you install the "Dell Data Protection Access" software for Finger Print authentication, it customises the lock screen and adds an ugly Dell logo (it ignores the user's current picture). How do I change the logo to the user's picture or customise the screen?

The tweaks.com Logon Changer tool will change the **background** but not the current user's picture - which remains as the ugly Dell logo.

Here's a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IW1Nd.jpg) of the screen - the Dell logo is not my current Windows user picture (it's currently the soccer ball picture and yeah, I tried changing it to see if it would trigger a change, but it didn't work).

Comment: The tweaks.com Logon Changer tool will change the **background** but not the current user's picture - which remains as the ugly Dell logo.

Comment: Try what's at the bottom of this thread: http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/software-os/f/3524/t/18807245.aspx

Comment: Thanks techie007, that worked. I took a backup of the DLL and I used Visual Studio to "hack" the Dell 128x128 bitmaps in the OEM_Resources.dll file and everything appears to be working. Bad form on Dell's part I believe.

Comment: You shouldn't have to use a driver for this purpose.  Windows 7 has built-in expandable support for this sort of authentication.  Infact the authentication method used by Dell is likely flawed.  You might want to make sure your fingerprint scanner is not storing your password in its own registry key.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Dell Data Protection | Security Tools Authentication

You will see a few on the list with this package, but it is only the authentication that you should remove to change this behavior.